# Powershell : I want to restrict the "variables" a user puts into my textbox. from a list if possible?

Tags: variables, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, restriction

I have a textbox with 3 customfields where the user can put in whatever he wants, and its parsed as answer.

Now I want to restrict it to a wordlist like that for my first input :

```
Question 1 : How old are you ?  
Answer (User input)  : `1-99`   (digits)
```

For my second question I need Answers combined of 2 Wordlists, like :

Question : Whats your mothers name ?

Assuming now that I have 2 List with possible names: All names of the world and all male names . So now I need to read out all names possible and subtract the other list.
(Allnames.txt - allmalenames.txt) = Answer2

So the user can only put in female names in the end, and no I don't have female  list first ;)

With that information i can resolve question 3 alone I guess :)

My Code is basicially this input box from the powershell tips of week.
[Custom input box](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx)
Any help is upvoted fast. If anything is unclear, let me know.

Comment: Wouldn't a drop-down or radio button list be a better option for a pre-defined list of items?

Comment: hey jscott, I thought about dropdown as well. for some of my tasks yes, for other not. And I want to learn how to make it both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$answer2 = <user input string>
$allnames = <path to all names file>
$malenames = <path to male names file>

if (
     ( Select-String -Path $allnames -Pattern "^$answer2$" -Quiet ) -and -not
     ( Select-String -Path $malenames -Pattern "^$answer2$" -Quiet )
   )

  { Do whatever needs done if it is a female name }

 else { Do whatever needs done if it is not a female name }
```

returns $true, $answer2 is a valid female name. Otherwise, not.

Comment: thank you very much, but still i have some trouble (since i am newbie)  how does it work with the if statement ? right now i get :Missing statement block after if ( condition ).